# How to append into div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm novice in jquery.
I want to prepend the value of an input into a new div. The problem is that the new value appears but also disappears immediately.This is the html code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" name="input" value="Add an item here" onfocus="value=''" class="add-item" >
  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit"><img src="img/pipe.png" alt=""></button>
</form>

<div class="col-lg-12 list">
                        <div class="list-row">
                            <div class="trash"></div>
                            <div class="list-tag">
                                 <p>chicken and salt</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pipe"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-row">
                            <div class="trash"></div>
                            <div class="list-tag">
                                 <p>chicken and salt</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pipe"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is the js:

```
$('.add-item').keypress(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode === 13) 
        {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var addListItem = $('<div class="trash"></div> '+value+' <div class="pipe"></div>');
        $('.col-lg-12').prepend(addListItem); 
        }
    });
```

Could you help me what is the problem?

Comment: Minor issue - I found that the text that you put into the input field stays there after the keypress (I'm not sure you want that). I added a $(this).val('') prior to the preventdefault/return false, and it clears the field.

Comment: Yes, this should've been my next question:) Thanks.

Comment: Do you also maybe how to add a class to the new item?

Comment: Well, you could put it in you class attribute '<div class='trash newclass'> or you could do a jQuery addClass at the end of your function.

Comment: I mean I'd like to add a class to the value. I tried it several ways.. without success.

Comment: Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VSe4y/. Put the value in a span, class the span, add CSS to the span class.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your page is reloaded after the js execution.

You have to stop the event propagation.

```
$('.add-item').keypress(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode === 13) 
        {
          var value = $(this).val();
          var addListItem = $('<div class="trash"></div> '+value+' <div class="pipe"></div>');
          $('.col-lg-12').prepend(addListItem);
          return false; // <-- this line
        }
    });
```

Pressing `return` in a form will submit it automatically.

Comment: In jquery you don't need to call both. Return false handles prevent default.

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmvLX/)**.

```
$('.add-item').keypress(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode === 13) 
        {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var addListItem = $('<div class="trash"></div> '+value+' <div class="pipe"></div>');
        $('.col-lg-12').prepend(addListItem); 
        }
});

$(".form-inline").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Your problem was, the form was getting submitted on 'enter' press. So to prevent default action use **[e.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, was working on a more specific solution.But The markup does not have Id's

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not calling [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) from within your function, meaning your form submits as usual and ultimately causes the page to reload.

Simply add that inside your `if` statement:

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```